# How to delete docker volumes without stopping docker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, teamcity, amazon-ecs

I have an issue where `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/` and `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` keep filling up my disk.

**Why?**

- I am running TeamCity agents on AWS ECS task containers in `docker-in-docker` mode.
- This generates volumes that cannot be deleted as they are all `in-use` state. Well at least I think it's because of this.

**Note**

- I only have 1 container running on the system.
- It is an amazon-linux machine.
- I don't want to stop docker because it detaches the agent from the server.

**What I've tried**

- Tried `docker system prune -af`
- Tried `docker volume prune -af`
- Tried `docker rmi`
- All of these don't reclaim the space because the volumes are `in-use`
- The only thing I can do is stop docker and delete `/var/lib/docker` and restart docker which I don't want to do.

Please help me out.

Comment: When you say you're using docker-in-docker, do you mean 1) you mounted the /var/run/docker.sock socket into the docker container, or 2) you are running a second docker server within a container? If 2, have you tried running those space-saving commands within the container?

Comment: @NickODell I did try runnung the space-saving commands within but in vain. But as I mentioned the volumes that are in /var/run/docker/volumes are all in use for watever reason. Even though there's only 1 container with 1 volume.

Comment: `docker volume prune -af` is an invalid command, `-a` flag does not exist for it. Before trying to purge anything it's always a good idea to look at what you already have - so please post the output of `docker system df -v`. Do it both from the host system and from the outer container, if you run DinD.

Comment: @RedBottle `in vain` Did you get an error? Did it work, but not free any space? Can you clarify whether you're using option 1 or 2 above?

Comment: @NickODell it says `Total reclaimed space: 0B` But there are like 20 voumes which are `in-use` state

Comment: "... because it detaches the agent from the server". This shouldn't be a problem if you store the token of the agent(s) and write it back in again when they're back online. You'll even get the history preserved free of charge.